# unable to deployWSPBuilder visual webpart in sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-part, deployment

i have created simple webpart in visual studio 2010 with the WSPBuilder Template (restricted to use this template. can not use the sharepoint tooling). 
I have added the Visual Webpart type. i found a .ascx file inside the Template->Control Template->MyWebpartName folder
on the design view i added 2 text boxes and a button. logic is in code behind like, on button click event want to copy text from textbox 1 to textbox 2. that it.

By right click the project node in the solution explorer i added the verified sharepoint site path in Package/PublishWeb to deploy the webpart. Now said build, and deployed. I got Done! message means successfully deployed.

I can see MyWebpartFolder in 14 hive as well (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES).but while i said Insert->Webpart there is no Custom folder available.  So thought it might be the issue about activation of feature , so checked the features on site. But i could not found that in feature list. What else i have to do ? Webpart scope is WebApplication level. i checked at webapplication level through central admin. i can see it is activated. but unable to add on any page. what else i need to do to get that webpart on page?

Comment: Did you check site collection features? That's where web parts usually are activated.

Comment: Yes i checked in site collection features also, but i could not found my webpart there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web part feature should be scoped to Site collection, not Web application.

Visual Web Parts create a .webpart file in the Web Part Gallery of a site collection - this is done at the scope of the site collection (obviously), and there's no "Web part gallery" at the Web Application level.